Random failure of unit tests after Junit5 migration
I have a muti-module project with nearly more that 500 unit test (UT) classes and 6000+ UTs.
I have recently migrated all the Unit Tests to JUnit5. After migration some UTs are passed when I run them individually but failing at random when I run them via the maven using command "mvn test".
First I tried to resolve them. But as they are failing randomly hence that approach was vague. Then I tried to use these annotations on class level to isolate those classes.
@ResourceLock("SYSTEM_PROPERTIES")

and
@Execution(SAME_THREAD)

These annotations also doesn't have any affect as those Unit Tests are still failing randomly.
I am using Java 8
Here are surefire configurations of pom.xml:
<plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
      <configuration>
        <forkCount>3</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
        <reportFormat>html</reportFormat>
        <argLine>@{argLine} -noverify -Xmx1g</argLine>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*Test.java</include>
        </includes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>

If reuseForks is false then all the tests are passed but it is making the build time very slow, hence I want it to be true only.

Show pom file, which Maven version, JDK version, surefire-plugin version, JUnit Jupiter version etc. do you use? Log output of a failure etc.. otherwise it's more or less impossible ...or at least to make some guess..

Define your acronyms on first use. Is "UT" unit-test? If so, say so.

@khmarbaise I have added the surefire configurations , As for errors they are total random . sometime Index out of bound exception, sometimes null pointer exception

@BasilBourque Defined them, Thank you for pointing it out

First why are using such an old version of maven-surefire-plugin? Also why configuration <include>..</include> is default... Also a failing test would help? That mentioned issues sounds like either the unit tests itself is not multi thread safe or your code is not? Without code it's impossible to even guess?  Also missing the log output ?

BTW: The given reportFormat is wrong because only brief and plain is supported (https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#reportFormat)... What you might search for is the https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/index.html instead...

@khmarbaise yeah you got it right, my code is not thread safe. That's why I have not enabled parallel execution after Junit5 upgrade. Even though the tests are failed.
